# Travis CI undefined reference to SDL2 and GLEW functions

Tags: travis-ci, sdl-2, automake, undefined-reference, glew

I'm trying to build my project with Travis CI (first time user). It uses automake and links against SDL2 and GLEW and compiles locally fine using `./configure && make` but fails on travis with undefined references to SDL2 and GL functions.

I have tried changing around the order the libs are linked in.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc
os:
  - linux
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa-dev libglew-dev libsdl2-dev autoconf automake autotools-dev
  - autoreconf --force --install
```

**Makefile.am**

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = mines
mines_SOURCES = \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/gl_shader.cpp \
    src/display_window.cpp \
    src/mines_sys.cpp \
    src/nes_cpu.cpp \
    src/nes_ppu.cpp \
    src/_nes_apu.cpp \
    src/nes_cart.cpp \
    src/nes_controllers.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper0.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper1.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper2.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper3.cpp \
    src/ines_mapper7.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/Sound_Queue.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/Wave_Writer.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/apu_snapshot.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Blip_Buffer.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Multi_Buffer.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Nes_Apu.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Nes_Namco.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Nes_Oscs.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Nes_Vrc6.cpp \
    src/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7/nes_apu/Nonlinear_Buffer.cpp
mines_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wno-c++11-narrowing -std=c++11 -Isrc/Nes_Snd_Emu-0.1.7 `pkg-config --cflags glew sdl2`
mines_LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs glew sdl2`
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

edit: Forgot to mention I also tried linking SDL2 and GLEW individually as well as pasting the output of pkg-config directly. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` in `configure.ac` so that the output of running `configure` will tell me something about whether pkg-config actually finds `glew.pc` and `sdl2.pc`:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLEW], [glew])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([SDL2], [sdl2])
```

Possibly even with an `AC_MSG_ERROR` as the fourth parameter `action-if-not-found`.

Then I would take a look at which build variables to add GLEW_LIBS and GLEW_CFLAGS to, and remember that `_LDFLAGS` is not for adding libraries to:

```
mines_CXXFLAGS += $(GLEW_CFLAGS)
mines_LDADD    += $(GLEW_LIBS)

mines_CXXFLAGS += $(SDL2_CFLAGS)
mines_LDADD    += $(SDL2_LIBS)
```

Then I would check whether the missing functions are actually present in the library versions on the Travis CI systems. Running Fedora locally and thus a relatively current system, I have been surprised a few times by how old the libraries on Travis CI's Ubuntu systems can be.

If Travis CI's systems just have old libraries unsupported by your source code, then it might be reasonable to add a version requirement to the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` invocation, or to AC_TRY_COMPILE or AC_TRY_LINK to ensure the required functions are present. Of course, this might then result in your program being officially unable to build on those systems.